# Opendaylight Cluster : Error resolving artifactorg.jolokia:jolokia-osgi:jar:1.1.5:Could not transfer artifact

Tags: cluster, maven

I'm using the integration distribution of Karaf (0.4.1-Beryllium) to deploy a 3 node cluster with Opendaylight Controller.

After using the deploy.py script and checking all the configuration files on each node are fine , I'm getting this error in karaf.log when I run ./karaf

| Event Dispatcher | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.1 | Error resolving artifactorg.jolokia:jolokia-osgi:jar:1.1.5:Could not transfer artifact org.jolokia:jolokia-osgi:jar:1.1.5 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): /usr/share/maven/conf: ...

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks!